# GeoServer HTTP header proxy authentication

Tags: geoserver

I have an instance of GeoServer running on Tomcat configured so that it can be accessed through both SSL on 443 and with non-SSL on port 80. The SSL connection requires client authentication and the non-SSL allows only anonymous read access, so the user must provide a client certificate in order to gain admin access. Here is a rough diagram showing the configuration

[image]

Because of new security requirements I have to do the authentication using oracle webgate on an httpd server configured to be a reverse-proxy for tomcat. In this configuration GeoServer would be doing authentication using "[HTTP Header Proxy Authentication](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/tutorials/httpheaderproxy/index.html)" Although this configuration works for the admin access, I would be forced to close off the non-secure connection to the world outside of the firewall since it's easy to bypass security by adding the right property to the HTTP header (i.e. set the oam_remote_user=admin in the header and you're logged in as an administrator). Here is a diagram showing this:

[image]

The problem is that we have a user base which depends on anonymous, read-only access to consume data. I feel this should be common enough an issue that other people have dealt with this, but haven't been successful at finding any posts on this. I have dug through GeoServer documentation and tried to fumble around with the settings without luck. I would hope that there is a setting where proxy authentication is only allowed through a particular IP address or port or a range of IP/Ports, but haven't found any such setting. Is there are way to restrict it to an ip address? If not is there another way to accomplish the same thing?